# C# DataGrid updating All Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

When a user clicks on the `datagrid`, all information loads into a `textbox` but when the user changes information and clicks `Update`, it updates all rows instead of the single row.

This is what I'm using:

```
string Query = "UPDATE database.taxi SET PickupLocation='" + 
 txtPickupLocation.Text +  "',PickupArea='" + comboBxPickupArea.Text +
 "' WHERE ID = ID ;";
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: have you check with break points and see what's passing in the where condition

Comment: but how do I make it so its a specific ID?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ID = ID
```

This condition is wrong,use `WHERE ID =` somenumber.ID will **always** be ID